# Type 'Pets' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'

Tags: swift

Instance methods "makePetMakeNoise()" and "feedPet()" are both in a class called Humans. When I put an integer in the call for makeNoise() [which is inside makePetMakeNoise] i get an error: Type 'Pets' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
I'm not sure what that means, can't find anything on google that helps in my case.

Also, when i call the eat() method inside of feedPet(), even though i didn't tell eat() to accept a parameter, when I call eat() it gives me the warning "missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm stuck.

```
func makePetMakeNoise(numberInput:Int) -> Int  {
    Pets.makeNoise(4) //Type 'Pets' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
    return random()

}

func feedPet() { // eat() doesn't accept any parameters. Why does is say "missing argument
    Pets.eat()       // for parameter #1 in call"?
}

class Pets: Humans {
func makeNoise(number:Int) {    //Here I created makeNoise() that accepts an Int
    if (pet == "Dog") {
        petNoise = "is barking"
    } else if (pet == "Cat") {
        petNoise = "says meow"
    }
    if (canMakeNoise == true) {
        for var x = 0; x <= number; x++ {
            println("\(petName) \(petNoise)")
        }
    } else if (canMakeNoise == false) {
        println("\(petName) remains silent.")
    }
}
func eat() {
    println("\(petName) is eating.")
}
```

Comment: `makeNoise()` is an *instance method*, but in `Pets.makeNoise(4)` you are calling it on the *type* and not on an instance. Same for `eat()`.

Comment: I understand these concepts a lot better now, thank you! I made makeNoise() and eat() type methods and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeNoise(number: Int)` and `eat()` are both instance methods for your class `Pets`.  As such, in order to call these methods, we must instantiate an object of this class.

```
let dog = Pet()
dog.makeNoise(4)
dog.eat()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, is there any way to call them through the Humans class?